# Floating LI inside LI

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the code editor so here it is

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1.1</li>
        <li>Item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2.1</li>
        <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

And I want to float elements to get a result like this:

[image: http://adamaweb.com/faqme/target.png]

Is it possible with that markup?

Comment: You have to nest the inner `ul` into the parent `li`

Comment: Dynamic example: http://jsfiddle.net/KdLMa/

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid in that the inner `<ul>`s must be contained in `<li>`s.  Assuming you won't nest more than one `<ul>`, this can be achieved by making all of the `<ul>` and `<li>` `display: inline-block` except the inner-most `<li>`s

http://jsfiddle.net/zeVwg/

Comment: I've seen the link and I don't understand why it doesn't works for me. Im gonna check the rest of the css in case something breaks it.

Comment: SOLVED. Cannot answer my question because of the reputation. Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that

**CSS**

```
ul li { 
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
li > ul { display: inline-block; }
li > ul li { display: block; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/emxKD/) to test it.

Comment: Need to add vertical-align: top; to ul li so they all align properly.

Comment: Updated. Thanks @Michael, I had forgot that :)

Comment: Thanks all. I've found a workaorund but I try that inline-block suggestion.

Comment: SOLVED. Cannot answer my question because of the reputation. Thank you all guys.

Comment: I've added the link to the fiddle so you can test it. Using my CSS you should obtain a result similiar to the one you want. (Of course, you'll have to adjust it according to your needs).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to adjust your HTML like so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>


    <li>Item1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've found a way withou changing markup. I post it in a sec. Thanks for yous answers.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li { float:left; position:relative; margin-left:10px; list-style:none; width:120px;}
ul li:first-child{ margin:0px;}

ul ul { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:none; width:100px; z-index:10;}

ul li:hover ul{ display:block;}

ul ul li{ float:none; margin-left:0px; margin-top:5px; width:100px;}
ul ul li:first-child{ margin-top:0px;}
```

I have made a navigation all of it in which when we hover the li its list will be appeared.